# Embedding a JavaFX application in a second application

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have written a little tool based on Java 8 using JavaFX. Let's call it App #1. It's an executable JAR which has only one view with some text fields and buttons.

Now I would like to "embed" this aplication in another JavaFX application, let's call this App #2, so the tool can be executed:

1. on its own
2. and also by "embedding" it into another application.

Is there such a mechanism? The main idea is that I only need to maintain App #1 and App #2 can just use/call it.

Comment: What is app#2 coded in?  Are you looking to have a separate instance, or just open a window?

Comment: App #2 is another JavaFX application.